# Как сделать что бы по команде poetry run start запускался fastapi проект? Что здесь не так?

Tags: python, fastapi, poetry

`pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
start = "uvicorn --reload app:create_app --port 5000"

poetry run start
```

ошибка

```
No file/folder found for package
```

Comment: А есть у вас модуль или пакет (папка) с именем app?

Comment: И что у вас create_app? По названию это похоже на функцию, но в uvicorn нужно запускать не функцию, а объект FastAPI, созданный например как `app = FastAPI()`, потом запускать как `uvicorn --reload имя_модуля:app --port 5000` (также возможно вы местами перепутали имя модуля и имя переменной app)

Comment: @insolor Да, эта команда отлично работает в консоли, но не работает через poetry

Comment: @insolo Я хотел узнать как правильно запускать консольные команды через poetry run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `[tool.poetry.scripts]` должна быть не команда (как если вы в командной строке вызываете), а имя пакета (пакетов) через точку, имя модуля и через двоеточие имя функции (или callable объекта), которую нужно импортировать из модуля и вызвать, например:

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
start = "имя_пакета.имя_модуля:start_uvicorn"
```

Это примерно аналогично такому коду:

```
from имя_пакета.имя_модуля import start_uvicorn
start_uvicorn()
```

В папке `имя_пакета` должен быть файл `имя_модуля.py`, в нем должна быть функция `start_uvicorn`, например, с таким содержимым:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

...

def start_uvicorn():
    uvicorn.run(app, port=5000, reload=True)
```

Соответственно, при запуске в командной строке `poetry run start` выполнится функция `start_uvicorn`.

- Документация: [The pyproject.toml file: scripts](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#scripts)
- Про использование скриптов в poetry на русском: [Poetry и скрипты](https://ru.hexlet.io/courses/python-setup-environment/lessons/poetry-and-scripts/theory_unit) (hexlet)

---

Для запуска именно команды, прописанной в pyproject.toml, можно использовать [poethepoet](https://github.com/nat-n/poethepoet). В pyproject.toml прописываете:

```
[tool.poe.tasks]
start = "uvicorn --reload app:create_app --port 5000"
```

Обратите внимание, что раздел конфига `[tool.poe.tasks]`, а не `[tool.poetry.scripts]`.

Запускаете:

```
poe start
```